# Private Nameservers and DNS for 2 dedicated servers

Tags: domains, dns, server, ip-address, nameserver

We just recently rent our second dedicated server with WHM from our hosting provider. But we have issues with the DNS and would like some input to find the solution.
The first server have its nameservers like:

ns1.myprivatename.com -> IP 10.0.0.1
ns2.myprivatename.com -> IP 10.0.0.2

In my domain registar there are the glue records for the myprivatename, again:
ns1.myprivatename.com -> IP 10.0.0.1
ns2.myprivatename.com -> IP 10.0.0.2
and everything works fine.

Now on the second server, the hosting provider set the same nameservers with new ips of the second server, so:

ns1.myprivatename.com -> IP 20.20.0.10
ns2.myprivatename.com -> IP 20.20.0.20

On the new server I have created new hosting accounts for a few new domains and set changed the NS settings for these domains to my above NS, according to the guidance of my hosting provider.

But I can't understand how could these sites be reached, since the ns1.myprivatename.com nameserver points to the ips of the first server.

Does this make any sense, or I should change hosting provider?

Comment: I used to be a web host and as such it made sense for me to run my own DNS. Nameservers are DNS- I say this only because of the title. It made sense in my case, but very likely not for yours. Why are you doing this?? Running your own DNS servers is serious business and requires significant knowledge especially in light of the security implications. It is not necessary for most websites even a fair number of them. Just let your registrar handle this for you. They made the investment and have the knowledge to be safe doing so.

Comment: @closetnoc: I appreciate your input, but honestly I didn't ask for a "father's advise" to tell me oh kid this is dangerous -better don't do it. I want to know if the above configuration my hosting provider did, makes any sense and will be able to work. Think it's a good question overall about DNS.

Comment: I certainly did not mean any insult. Back in the day, there were not too many options- either pay Network Solutions or do it yourself. Today, there are so many affordable options that even a web host has to think twice. We get questions like this from people who do not enough and can seriously get themselves into real trouble. DNS is the most hacked Internet service next to PHP over the web. My DNS servers were completely independent on two separate networks which was a requirement to be an authority. I had both sets of DNS pull from a master on yet a third network that I used for monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue at all in running your own DNS servers and cPanel as you have seen has its own built in DNS server for webmasters to host DNS on the cPanel server. In order to make this work you will have to make sure that the DNS server's IP addresses are changed and reflected appropriately.

**On server 1...**
ns1.domain.com > IP 10.0.0.1
ns2.domain.com > IP 10.0.0.2

On Server 2...
ns3.domain.com > IP 20.20.0.10
ns4.domain.com > IP 20.20.0.20

At that point what you tell your users to do for their domain names is that users on server 1 point their name server records to ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com and the users on server two to point their name server records to ns3.domain.com and ns4.domain.com.

By not using the server domains themselves and defining specific domains for the name servers themselves this will enable you to move the DNS servers out of cPanel at a later date should you use and to merge all your DNS hosting into a single set of servers for all of your clients (cPanel provides a free software stack for this called cPanel WHM DNSONLY with the instructions at https://lowendbox.com/blog/handle-dns-properly-with-cpanel/)